# how to make a web based system that connects only the authorized user in the wi-fi access

Tags: wifi

this is for our thesis project. we proposed to study the Wi-Fi security in most related to the users.

Comment: Hi @Bernadete - welcome to Security Stack Exchange. This question unfortunately does not meet our requirements as it is not answerable, so I have closed it, however it can be reopened if you can edit it into a more answerable form. Have a look at the faq (at the top of the page) for guidance on how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method is called "Captive Portal".

When the client first connects, all web page requests are intercepted and sent to the the login page instead. (Any non-web traffic sent at this point is dropped.)

One the user authenticates, the access point notes that it's authenticated, and subsequently allows traffic from that connection through to the Internet.